# Why do ceramic insulators have a stacked disc structure?

Tags: power, high-voltage, ceramic, insulation

I've seen these stacked-disc structures on high voltage power lines everywhere. I could not find any information regarding this particular shape, though.

[image: Insulator on Railways (From Wikimedia Commons)]

[image: Another example of insulator]

From what I've noticed, high voltage ceramic insulators only insulate conductors end-to-end (not inside to outside, like traditional plastic insulators). I can only assume the shape makes it difficult for an electric arc to travel along the ceramic material, as opposed to, say, along a solid cylindrical piece.

Why exactly are ceramic insulators shaped like that? Is it to reduce cost? Thermal concerns (from possible electric arcs)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Electricity can more easily travel across a surface of an insulator. If the surface is made longer it makes the surface path longer and thus is able to withstand higher voltages before breaking down.

Comment: Plus the shape is intended to ensure at least part of the "cup" stays dry in most normal weather; water tends to reduce the surface impedance.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Indeed, imagine if it was a smooth, ceramic cylinder. In heavy rain, a rivulet of water could easily run along its length between the two terminals.

Comment: @BrianDrummond could be added as another answer